# How do I redirect from "domain.com/folder/index.html" to "domain.com/folder"

Tags: redirect

My site runs on nginx

I have the code to redirect my root index.html to domain name but I don't know how to redirect index.html files in folders to point to the folder for 301 redirect

example root/folder/index.html to root/folder

this code worked in htaccess to redirect root index.html to domain name
    `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: What is the Operating System of your web server?  Can you show your redirect code that you have so far?

Comment: Are you using PHP? Node? Ruby? What? This question is not specific enough and I would down vote it if I wasn't cheap with my low amount of rep

Comment: my sites runs on nginx. I updated the request, thanks. Looking for an htaccess solution